# Eazfuscator.NET error for custom build configuration

Tags: obfuscation, eazfuscator

I’m using Eazfuscator for a while for my project and everything is working as it should be until, I created a copy of Release build configuration called “Release-Internal”. I also updated the post build event and changed the script to “if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" NEQ "Debug"...". Now all of my projects obfuscate without any problems but only one of them displays the following error:

> (EF-1099 error occurred.
>
> 4> Obfuscator can not load the input assembly or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> 4> To resolve this issue you can:
>
> 4> - Specify a probing path
>
> 4> - Put a missing assembly near the input file
>
> 4> More information can be found in Eazfuscator.NET Documentation at
>
> 4> Troubleshooting -> Error Codes Knowledge Base -> EF-1099 chapter.)

The interesting part is if I change the active configuration to “Release” the same project obfuscates without any problems. The difference between the “Release” and “Release-Internal” configurations are just that the “Release-Internal” has an extra conditional compilation symbol called INTERNAL.

I also build the project without obfuscation with the “Release-Internal” config. The application build succeed and executed as it should be.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

From the build output, it seems you are building projects in parallel.

I'm thinking there's a missing dependency at the time Eazfuscator.NET tries to load your assembly.

I recommend trying to set the "maximum number of parallel project builds" to 1 in Visual Studio IDE > Tools > Options > "Projects and Solutions" and try again.

The event viewer may have some more information (ex. side-by-side errors).

You can also try to enable assembly bind failure logging to try to identify which specific dependencies could not be found.  See: [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net/1527249#1527249)

It could be as simple as setting "Copy Local" to true in the project's reference properties of the missing dependency.

You can read the "EF-1099: Unable to load input assembly, reflection load failed" help topic in "Eazfuscator.NET Documentation.chm" > Troubleshooting > Error Codes Knowledge Base.  The help document for Eazfuscator.NET 3.2.278.32704 has "Instructions on enabling the architecture-neutral loading mode of Eazfuscator.NET" in the same help topic.